# date.format is not a function reacr-dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-dates

I was trying to use singleDatePicer from react-dates,which is a popular date picker library by airbnb, on selecting a date, it throws the error `date.format is not a function`, and just breaks, my code sandbox link is -> https://08cg1.csb.app/. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onDateChange={(date) => {setDate(date);}}
```

Here, Don't change the date format and then set the state.
Just set the state directly.

If you want to display that selected date somewhere else, there use the **moment**.

The issue was, once you changed the date format, that format is not supporting as value.

Comment: Hey, Thank you, this is way more explainable

Answer (score 1):

`singleDatePicker` will accept moment object as `date` props so you need to change `onDateChange` like below:-

```
onDateChange={(date) => setDate(date)};
```